# Call function that populates carrierwave textarea on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carrierwave

I have JS that is meant to create a function that populates a carrierwave text field, then calls the function on click. For some reason the code I have does not work. I have looked around for similar questions already but no solutions have worked. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
  <div id="quote" class="quote"> 
    <div class="field">
      <textarea  placeholder="Enter text..." class="textarea" rows="4" cols="70"  <%= f.text_area :quote %> 

        <a id="randomQuote" class="random_quote">Populate Text Area</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
function populateQuote(){
document.getElementById("#new_tile_quote")[0].value = "TESTING";
}


var quoteButton =document.getElementById('randomQuote');
        quoteButton.addEventListener('click', function (){
            populateQuote();
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: change `button.addEventListener` to `quoteButton.addEventListener`, also give space between class and rows property `class="textarea"  rows="4"`

Comment: @vinayakj After changing these two errors, it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes there are more errors in code, so I corrected all and added code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function populateQuote(){
document.getElementById("new_tile_quote").value = "TESTING";
}


var quoteButton =document.getElementById('randomQuote');
        quoteButton.addEventListener('click', function (){
            populateQuote();
  });
```

```html
  <div id="quote" class="quote"> 
    <div class="field">
      <textarea  placeholder="Enter text..." class="textarea" rows="4" cols="70"> 
</textarea>
      <br/>
        <a id="randomQuote" class="random_quote">Populate Text Area</a>
    </div>
  </div>

New quote: <input id="new_tile_quote" />
```